# Angular Show All When No Filter Is Supplied

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, filter

I have been working on trying to get my Angular application to show all results if no filter is selected. I have looked at similar questions on here, but their answers did not work for my application for some strange reason.

I have it working initially, but after a filter is applied, and removed, no data is displayed.

My working demo is at the following [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rzgWr/389/)

**My HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<h4>Industries</h4>
<div ng-init="group = (industries | groupBy:'industry_id')" style="width:100%">
    <div ng-repeat="ind in industries"   style="width:100px; float:left;">
        <b><input type="checkbox" ng-model="useIndustries[$index]"/>{{ind.industry_name}}</b>
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<h4>Types</h4>
<div ng-init="group2 = (types | groupBy:'industry_type_id')" style="width:100%">
    <div ng-repeat="type in types" style="width:100px;float:left;">
        <b><input type="checkbox" ng-model="useTypes[$index]"/>{{type.type_name}}</b>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
<div>
    <ul>
        <li  ng-repeat="est in establishments | filter:(!!filterIndustries() || undefined) && filterIndustries()"><p><b>{{est.est_name}} - {{est.industry_id}} - {{est.industry_type_id}}</b></p></li>
    </ul>    
</div>
```

**My JS**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope, filterFilter) {
    $scope.useIndustries = [];
    $scope.useTypes = [];

    $scope.filterIndustries = function () {

        return function (p) {

            if ($scope.useIndustries.length > 0) {

                for (var i in $scope.useIndustries) {
                    if ((p.industry_id == $scope.group[i] && $scope.useIndustries[i])) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            if ($scope.useTypes.length > 0) {

                for (var i in $scope.useTypes) {
                    if (p.industry_type_id == $scope.group2[i] && $scope.useTypes[i]) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }

        };

    };

    $scope.industries = [
        { industry_name: "Italian", industry_id: 1}, 
        { industry_name: "Indian", industry_id: 2}, 
        { industry_name: "Spanish", industry_id: 3} 

    ];



    $scope.types = [
        { type_name: "Eat-In", industry_type_id: 1}, 
        { type_name: "Fast Food", industry_type_id: 2}, 
        { type_name: "Takeout", industry_type_id: 3}
    ];

    $scope.establishments = [
        {est_name: 'Luigis Pizza Kitchen', industry_id: 1, industry_type_id:2},
        {est_name: 'Pizza Plus', industry_id: 1, industry_type_id:1},
        {est_name: 'Authentic Mexican Grill', industry_id: 3, industry_type_id:1},
        {est_name: 'Tacos R Us', industry_id: 3, industry_type_id:3},
        {est_name: 'Taste Of India', industry_id: 2, industry_type_id:1},
        {est_name: 'Indian Food Emporium', industry_id: 2, industry_type_id:3}
    ];    
}


var uniqueItems = function (data, key) {
    var result = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var value = data[i][key];

        if (result.indexOf(value) == -1) {
            result.push(value);
        }

    }
    return result;
};

myApp.filter('groupBy',
            function () {
                return function (collection, key) {
                    if (collection === null) return;
                    return uniqueItems(collection, key);
        };
    });
```

I have been working on this for a while, and am curious if anyone can see any glaring issues that are causing this not to function quite "right". I realize that it has to be an error on my part. My knowledge of Angular is minimal at best.

I would genuinely appreciate any help on this subject.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must return collection first and after you have to check whether is all items removed or not.

**Filter**

```js
$scope.filterIndustries = function () {

    return function (p) {
        if ($scope.useIndustries.length == 0 && $scope.useTypes.length == 0) {
            return p;
        }
        var isShowAll = true;
        if ($scope.useIndustries.length > 0) {
            for (var i in $scope.useIndustries) {
                if ((p.industry_id == $scope.group[i] && $scope.useIndustries[i])) {
                    return true;
                }
                if($scope.useIndustries[i]){
                    isShowAll = false;
                }

            }
        }
        if ($scope.useTypes.length > 0) {

            for (var i in $scope.useTypes) {
                if (p.industry_type_id == $scope.group2[i] && $scope.useTypes[i]) {
                    return true;
                }
                if($scope.useTypes[i]){
                    isShowAll = false;
                }
            }

        }
        if(isShowAll)
         return p;

    };

};
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ju8jvmek/)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I didn't even think to use that kind of check. As I'm sure you saw, I had a commented out check PRIOR to the filtering that was in a similar vein to your fiddle, but I wasn't quite there. Thanks again for the help! I would plus your answer up, but I don't have quite enough rep yet to do so. But when I get enough, I shall return here to award the points where they are due for your help.

Answer (score 1):

As you are returning array while they got match criteria by using `return true`, But if there is no any filter selected then you have to return whole array by adding the condition on top before applying crieteria.

**Filter**

```
$scope.filterIndustries = function () {
    return function (p) {
        if ($scope.useIndustries.length == 0 && $scope.useTypes.length == 0) return p;
        if ($scope.useIndustries.length > 0) {
            for (var i in $scope.useIndustries) {
                if ((p.industry_id == $scope.group[i] && $scope.useIndustries[i])) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        if ($scope.useTypes.length > 0) {

            for (var i in $scope.useTypes) {
                if (p.industry_type_id == $scope.group2[i] && $scope.useTypes[i]) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    };
};
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rzgWr/392/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I would choose your answer, but @engincancan's answer made a little bit more sense to me, and I was able to get it all working. I appreciate you help, though. I would plus up both of your answers, but alas, I don't have quite enough reputation yet.

Comment: @Bjornir the answer you have accepted does improved version of mine answer..If you are satisfied with it then I don't have any problem as you are satiefied with improved answer..instead of finding first answer which solved your issue...You could upvote now 15 reputation in enough for it..

Comment: Indeed it is, and I appreciate your initial help. I tinkered with it, and just couldn't quite get it to work, but I do appreciate it. It appears I do have enough now, and have upvoted.

Comment: @Bjornir thanks for appreciation.Glad to help you.:)